# Сравнение значений из одного столбца

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Есть следующая таблица:

[image]

Необходимо заполнить promo_cw последовательно идущими числами от 0, в случае если в period_id есть также непрерывная последовательность чисел. Если последовательность в period_id нарушается, то значения в promo_cw обнуляются.

Ожидаемый результат:
Столбец promo_cw состоит из последовательности чисел, которая заканчивается при прерывании последовательности чисел в столбце period_id. После прерывания со следующей строки столбца promo_cw новая последовательность начинается с 0 и цикл повторяется.

На данный момент есть такой код:

```
for j in range(0, 1000): #для заполнения promo_cw
    for i in promo.index: #для итерации по period_id
        now = promo.loc[i, 'period_id'] 
        prev = promo.loc[i - 1, 'period_id'] + 1
        if now == prev:
            promo_cw.append(j)
        else:
            promo_cw.append(0)
promo
```

Выдает

KeyError: -1

Заранее спасибо

Comment: А `promo_id` заполнено как показано? Наверное, можно по нему сгруппировать и пронумеровать уже внутри групп потом.

Comment: замените скриншоты текстом.

Comment: @CrazyElf, если отсортировать, то promo_id - это последовательность чисел, которая прерывается на разных значениях. Начало каждой последовательности также изменяется каждый раз.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде ничего сложного, только немного подумать, ну и знать про всякие аггрегатные функции типа `cumsum` и `cumcount`. Здесь я и создаю тестовый датафрейм и вычисляю поля, всё в "векторном" виде, без циклов:

```
import pandas as pd

period_id = [x for x in range(15) if x not in [5,8,12]]

promo = pd.DataFrame({'period_id': period_id})
promo['promo_id'] = ((promo.period_id - promo.period_id.shift()).fillna(1) != 1).cumsum() + 1
promo['promo_cw'] = promo.groupby('promo_id').cumcount()
promo
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом наверняка придёт **MaxU**, уважаемый, и сделает тоже самое через `query`.

Comment: подскажите еще, пожалуйста, как это можно привести к итоговому виду как на фото "Ожидаемый результат"? 

Большое спасибо!

Comment: А в каком смысле? По цифрам вроде уже и оно. Или нужна раскраска?

Comment: с store_id и sales_volume

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вот такое красивое(имхо) решение придумал)

Можно и попроще, но здесь свое и универсальное) В частности можно укоротить, просто перенеся логику `__iadd__` в сам метод `__call__`.

```
class X:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__num = 0

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.__num = self.__num + other
        return self.__num
        
    def __call__(self, num=None):
        if num is None:
            return self.__iadd__(1)
        else:
            self.__num = num
            return self.__num

i = X()
dictionary = {f'{el}': i() if el-1 in array else i(0) for el in array}
```

UPD:
Ну и, конечно же, вместо словаря и списка тут должны быть пандасовские  серии, просто у меня проблемки с пандасом