# Как группировать по одному столбцу и по разнице соседних значений == 1 в другом столбце?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, group-by

Имеется таблица:

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'store_id': [4168621, 4168621, 4168621, 4168621, 4168621, 4168624, 4168624, 4168626, 4168626],
                          'period_id': [191, 192, 194, 195, 196, 191, 192, 193, 194] })
```

data1:

```
   store_id  period_id
0   4168621        191
1   4168621        192
2   4168621        194
3   4168621        195
4   4168621        196
5   4168624        191
6   4168624        192
7   4168626        193
8   4168626        194
```

Необходимый выход:

```
data2 = pd.DataFrame({'store_id': [4168621, 4168621, 4168621, 4168621, 4168621, 4168624, 4168624, 4168626, 4168626],
                          'period_id': [191, 192, 194, 195, 196, 191, 192, 193, 194],
                          'promo_id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4],
                          'promo_cw': [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1] })
```

data2:

```
   store_id  period_id  promo_id  promo_cw
0   4168621        191         1         0
1   4168621        192         1         1
2   4168621        194         2         0
3   4168621        195         2         1
4   4168621        196         2         2
5   4168624        191         3         0
6   4168624        192         3         1
7   4168626        193         4         0
8   4168626        194         4         1
```

Рабочий код для строк под индексами 0 - 6:

```
data1['promo_id'] = ((data1.period_id - data1.period_id.shift()).fillna(1) != 1).cumsum() + 1
data1['promo_cw'] = data1.groupby('promo_id').cumcount()
```

```
   store_id  period_id  promo_id
0   4168621        191         1
1   4168621        192         1
2   4168621        194         2
3   4168621        195         2
4   4168621        196         2
5   4168624        191         3
6   4168624        192         3
7   4168626        193         3
8   4168626        194         3
```

Рабочий код для строк под индексами 7 - 8:

```
data1['promo_id'] = ((data1.store_id == data1.store_id.shift()).fillna(1) == 0).cumsum() + 1
data1['promo_cw'] = data1.groupby('promo_id').cumcount()
```

```
   store_id  period_id  promo_id
0   4168621        191         2
1   4168621        192         2
2   4168621        194         2
3   4168621        195         2
4   4168621        196         2
5   4168624        191         3
6   4168624        192         3
7   4168626        193         4
8   4168626        194         4
```

Через символ "|" объединить не получилось.

Как можно объединить эти фрагменты кода, чтобы он работал для всей таблицы?

Comment: Зачем вы лепите сюда скриншоты, ей-богу? Ну вставьте текстом уже вывод.

Comment: что за столбец `promo_ cw`? он у вас в коде нигде не задается

Comment: user451104 — новый участник сайта. Будьте снисходительны, задавая уточняющие вопросы, комментируя и отвечая. Почитайте про нормы поведения.

Comment: вам уже делались замечания по поводу скриншотов: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1303685/%d0%a1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d1%86%d0%b0 , а так же по поводу того, как задавать вопросы.

Comment: Исправлено. Вы можете это сказать более уважительно, я не понимал как это сделать. Спасибо

Comment: не путайте уважение с вежливостью.

Comment: Спасибо спасибо

Comment: +1 за качественное оформление вопроса с примерами входных данных и ожидаемым результатом...

Comment: Спасибо, извините, что не с первого раза :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
data1["promo_id"] = (
    (data1["store_id"] != data1["store_id"].shift().bfill())
    |
    (data1["period_id"].diff().fillna(1).ne(1))
).cumsum().add(1)
data1['promo_cw'] = data1.groupby("promo_id").cumcount()
```

результат:

```
In [77]: data1
Out[77]:
   store_id  period_id  promo_id  promo_cw
0   4168621        191         1         0
1   4168621        192         1         1
2   4168621        194         2         0
3   4168621        195         2         1
4   4168621        196         2         2
5   4168624        191         3         0
6   4168624        192         3         1
7   4168626        193         4         0
8   4168626        194         4         1
```

PS если хотите разобраться как это работает, вам придется запускать отдельные кусочки и смотреть, что из этого получается, а потом последовательно комбинировать их и опять смотреть на промежуточные результаты...

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно!